# moment Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined at time

Tags: javascript, css, time, momentjs

I have this error for this line of code

```
var FullDate = moment(1499153561479).add(currentSeconds, 'seconds').tz(citiesT[id]).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss a");
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is `citiesT[id]` exactly? An invalid timezone perhaps?

Comment: its an object contain keys (the ids ) and values mean name of cities

Comment: Give us a concrete value.

Comment: var cities = {
                "309": "Dubai",
            };

Comment: `"Dubai"` is not a valid time zone identifier, you have to use `"Asia/Dubai"` instead. Which version of moment and moment-timezone are you using? Using the lastest one you should have an error like this: _Moment Timezone has no data for Dubai. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/._ Can you provide a fiddle or a snippet showing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `moment-timezone` library, CDN is `http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.1/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js` and `moment.min.js` library, CDN is `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js`

Then your code will work when you have all the variables defined like

```
currentSeconds = 10000;
var citiesT = ["America/Los_Angeles"];
var id= 0;
var FullDate = moment(1499153561479).add(currentSeconds, 'seconds').tz(citiesT[id]).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss a");
alert(FullDate);
```

For you simplicity and work around here is the working link to [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jfpek75r/1/)